# Natural deduction derivation of $\forall x (B(x) \to C(x)) \vdash \neg \exists y (B(y) \land \neg C(y))$

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, natural-deduction

I am working on this derivative and I got 3 errors; however, the steps seem correct to me. I don't quite understand the explanations it gives beside the errors.

[image]

Reference:
https://proofs.openlogicproject.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Line 2: Is not a proper application of the rule $\forall E$

That proof checker assumes that the term in the conclusion of $\forall E$ must be an individual constant, not a variable. The letter $y$ is interpreted as a variable, so you have to pick a letter that's understood by the proof checker as a constant symbol, for example $a$, instead.

> Line 4: Cites too few ranges of lines for the rule $\exists E$

The proof checker is right, you applied the $\exists E$ rule incorrectly. From $\exists y (By \land \neg Cy)$ you may *not* conclude $By \land Cy$, for an arbitrary term $y$. Just because $By \land \neg Cy$ is true of *some* term doesn't mean we can be sure it is true of the particular term $y$. This would be the inference we can do with $\forall E$. Instead, the $\exists E$ rule looks like this:
[image]

You must *assume* $By \land \neg Cy$ for some term $y$ -- as before, this has to be a constant symbol, such as $b$ -- and for some convenient conclusion formula $\mathcal{B}$ that you can derive from this assumption, you may conclude $\mathcal{B}$ outside of the subproof by applying $\exists y$ on the assumption $\exists y (By \land \neg Cy)$ and the subproof from $Bb \land \neg Cb$ to $\mathcal{B}$. The idea of $\exists E$ is: If we know that $\mathcal{B}$ follows under the assumption of the existentially quantified over formula applied to a concrete term $b$, and we know that at least one such term exists, then we can conclude $\mathcal{B}$ for sure.
So instead of what you did, open a new subproof with assumption $Bb \land \neg Cb$ for a new constant symbol $b$, try to derive a convenient formula from it (reading the explanation of the next error will get you in the right direction about what a useful candidate for such a conclusion would be), and then close the subproof by doing $\exists E$ on the assumption $\exists y (By \land \neg Cy)$ and the subproof from $Bb \land \neg Cb$ to the new conclusion $\mathcal{B}$.

> Line 8: Is not a proper application of the rule $\neg I$

The proof checker wants the contradiction you derived from $\exists y By \land Cy$ to be explicit in the form of $\bot$:
[image]

The contradiction between $Cy$ and $\neg Cy$ is so far only implicit. So you need an application of $\neg E$

[image]

on $Cy$ and $\neg Cy$ to show that the assumption led to a contradiction ($\bot$), then you can apply $\neg I$ on the subproof that ends with this contradiction.

Comment: I tried again, but still get errors-- "Is not a proper application of the rule ¬I (for the line(s) cited)." 
my answer:      https://imgur.com/a/I7tIAyC

Comment: Because you didn't do the $(\neg E)$ step. You need the $\bot$ in order to apply $(\neg I)$.

Comment: And you only need ($\neg I$) once, at the very end, before that will come the ($\exists E$) step. You derive a contradiction ($\bot$) from assumption $Bb \land \neg Cb$, carry that contradiction over into the outer subproof with the existential assumption by the use of $(\exists E$), then conclude that since from $\exists y ...$ you got a contradiction ($\bot$), the assumption $\exists y ...$ must have been false, and you get $\neg \exists y ...$ with $(\neg I)$.

Comment: "Am I closer.....? https://imgur.com/a/U3YVoIT

Comment: Think again about what you want, and how the $\exists E$ rule works. You don't want to introduce a new existential statement -- you want to eliminate it. So the steps on lines 9 and 10 are not helpful, and 11 is not a correct application of $\exists E$. Read my second comment again, the whole answer is in there.

Comment: You got the contradiction in the subproof with assumption $Bb \land \neg Cb$, that's good. But now you don't want to introduce a negation on $Bb \land \neg Cb$. Instead, you want to show that the assumption $\exists y(By \land\neg Cy)$ led to a contradiction, so you want to carry over the conclusion $\bot$ form the inner subroof into the middle-outer one (the one that starts with $\exists y(By \land \neg Cy)$ as assumption). That's precisely what the $\exists E$ rule allows you to do: You showed that some conclusion ($\bot$) follows from assuming $Bb \land \neg Cb$ for a concrete term $b$, ...

Comment: ... and since you know that at least one such term exists, you can conclude $\bot$ from the existential statement $\exists y By \land \neg Cy$. (Note that in the $\exists E$ rule, you have to cite both the assumption $\exists y (By \land \neg Cy)$ and the subproof from $Bb \land \neg Cb$ to $\bot$.) And then, when you derived $\bot$ from assumption $\exists y (By \land \neg Cy)$, you can finally do the negation introduction and end up with the desired negated existential statement.

Comment: I got it!!!!!!! Thanks!